# what is the ssh public key

Tags: windows, ssh, key, git-bash

I just created an SHH pair using git bash in win 10

I get the pair shown in the attached image.

[image]

In Win 7 one of them was the pub key, but in Win 10 they have the same name, so what is the public key?

Answer (score 1):

The key with the `.pub` extension

There should be an option to show the extension in the file explorer. Also, you should be able to right-click the file to get extra info.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same name both in Windows 7 and Windows 10, they are both called **id_rsa**. They have different extensions though. Your private key has no extension and is shown as *File* in Explorer, while the public key has a `.pub` extension, which is not shown by Explorer. However, Explorer mistakenly misunderstands "pub", that stands for "public" and assumes that it's "Microsoft Publisher Document" :)

So the one with the green P on it is the public key.

If not seeing extensions in Windows 10 bothers you, then you might want to read an article about how to make them visible in Explorer: https://fileinfo.com/help/windows_10_show_file_extensions